# QR decomposition of column swapped matrix

Tags: matrices

How does the upper triangular matrix $R$ of a QR decomposition change when you swap the columns of the original matrix? I've tried multiplying both sides of $A = Q R$ by a permutation matrix $P$, but $R P$ isn't an upper triangular matrix anymore. I'm probably missing a simple relationship somewhere.